Python importing the files partially from the same script
I have a folder structure as follows:
lib
|
|
|-MainScriptsDir
|      |
|      |-subDir
|        |
|        |- Mod_1 -> Importing Numpy 
|        |- Mod_2 -> Importing Mod_4 
|        |- Mod_3 -> Importing Mod_1,Mod_2
|        |- Mod_4
|
|-TestsDir
|   |
|   SubDirTests
|     |
|     |-Mod_a
|     |-Mod_b --> Importing Mod_3 and able to access functions in Mod_1 but not able to access Mod_2
|
|

The problem is pretty much explained in the tree structure itself.
If Mod_1 namespace is available to Mod_b, why isn't Mod_2?
BTW, The error I am getting in Mod_b is ImportError but not ModuleNotFoundError
Please let me know if I have to do any read-up or if I misunderstood anything.
I feel that it has something to do with having an init.py file and packaging.
Edit:
Few additional details on how I am importing the functions:
In Mod_b,
I am importing Mod_3 like "from lib.MainScriptsDir.SubDir.Mod_3 import *"
Inside Mod_3, I am doing "from Mod_1 import *" and "from Mod_2 import *" also, it doesn't give me error when I am calling(from within Mod_3) a function that depends on the imports, its working fine.
Really sorry that I couldn't provide the actual code for privacy reasons as I am a working professional.
But then, I have created the same structure in my IDE to provide you the code with some other functions like add (takes two ints and returns their sum), multiply(same as add but returns product), etc. and I am getting the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mod_1'
inside Mod_b
Edit2:
I am able to resolve this issue if I modify my import statement inside Mod_3 for Mod_2 as follows:
from lib.MainScriptsDir.SubDir.Mod_2
(I didn't touch import statement for Mod_1 i.e., it is still
"from Mod_1 import *")
But, definitely am not sure what's happening here.

it is important what you have in code, not only tree structure.

to the O.P. you really have to show us the code you are using to import Mod3 and the code to use Mod2 from ModB. so that an answer can be given.
